# Backbone/chaplinJS : How to check for key existence in object

Tags: backbone.js, chaplinjs

```
{
                  "providerProperties": [
                    {
                      "key": "hotelnum",
                      "value": "123"
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "contract",
                      "value": "ABC"
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "Sequence",
                      "value": "1213"
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "lastFourDigit",
                      "value": "5454"
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "shop",
                      "value": "abc"
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "bookingEmailAddress",
                      "value": "abc@gmail.COM"
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "numOfRooms",
                      "value": "1"
                    }
}
```

Backbone/chaplinJS : How to check for key existence in object.
for example want to check of key "numOfRooms" is available or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use underscore method [`findWhere`](http://underscorejs.org/#findWhere) like `_.findWhere(yourObject.providerProperties, {key: "numOfRooms"});` if the result is not `undefined` then it is present